# Comparing items using number codes (JSON)

Tags: objective-c, xcode, json, dropbox

in my app, the users can create groups. When a user creates a group, a new folder is uploaded on dropbox, and inside there is a JSON file like this:

```
{"group":"0864798478"}
```

The code you see is generated randomly in the following way:

```
NSString *randomKey = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.10u", arc4random()];
```

Then I have a table view which displays all the folders (groups). But I would like the UITableView to display only the groups which mach with the codes the iPad has saved on.

So if I have:

```
{"group a":"0864797073"}
{"group b":"0764898478"}
{"group c":"2864758479"}
```

And on the iPad there is a file containing the code:

```
0864797073 (group a)
```

The table View displays only that group, not all.

How can I do this??

Thanks in advance for the help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use JSONKit or SBJson for parse JSON files and obtain NSDictionaries with the data. Then you can create a NSDictionary in wich you could save the result of comparing previous dictionaries, an then show the result in the table with method tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath. OR, make the comparison in the method tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath. Good Luck!

EDIT:

If the file reads:

```
{"group a":"0864797073"}
```

You parse it and get a dictionary like in wich "group a" will be the KEY and the NSString "0864797073" will be the value. So to compare the dictionary wich holds group a with wich holds group b you have to do:

```
if([[firstParsedJson objectForKey:@"group a"] isEqualToString:[secondParsedJson objectForKey:@"group b"]])
{
   //Do some stuff...
}
```

Where firstParsedJson and secondParsedJason are NSDictionaries that represent parsed json with, for example, SBJson.

Comment: Oh, I did not tell that I already had SBJson so my question  becomes: "how do you compare two NSDictionaries?"... if([dic1 isEqualToDictionary: dic2]);

Comment: Yes, but since every group (every folder) has just one of this: {"group a":"0864797073"} with a unique number, I can't parse all of them to see if they match. So, how can I for example add a new {"group a":"0864797073"}  to the same file with ought replacing the previous groups?

Answer (score 0):

As Luis has mentioned, SBJson is the easiest framework that you allows you to parse JSON using objective-C. You can parse the JSON and go through the CellForRowAtIndexPath delegate method of the UITableView to show all the values.
If you have having any troubles with visulizing the JSON then this [link](http://chris.photobooks.com/json/default.htm) will help you to get a better idea of how your JSON is being created.